# XmlPullParser get file from filesystem

Tags: android, xml-parsing, intellij-idea, xmlpullparser

I my app creater xml file in Android file system. I ned parse this file with XmlPullParser, but I get error wile compilation: "variable parser might not have been initialized". My code:

```
InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("settings.xml");
XmlPullParser parser;
parser.setInput(inputStream, null);
```

Have no idea, how to repair it. I use Intellij IDEA12 and Android 2.3 SDK.

Comment: first initialize your paser like in my code.

Answer (score 5):

> I use Eclipse and the below code has worked for me:

You might be missing the below first line:

```
 XmlPullParserFactory xppf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
 xppf.setNamespaceAware(true); 
 XmlPullParser xpp = xppf.newPullParser();

 File myXML = new File("myXML.xml"); // give proper path            
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myXML);

 xpp.setInput(fis, null);
```

Comment: I try it's early and it's works. But I want to do this with only XmlPullParser. Can I do it?

Comment: You need to instanstiate your XmlPullParser to use it. and to do that you need XmlPullParserFactory. My code works for me. And this is the way i would do it. You can check google docs if required.

Answer (score 3):

Its working code in eclipes but dont know about Intellij IDEA12

write this code to open and get xml from assets
or modify according to your need

```
try {           

    XmlPullParserFactory     xppf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser  = xppf.newPullParser();                  
    AssetManager manager = context.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream input = manager.open("createDb.xml");
    xpp.setInput(input, null);
    int type = xpp.getEventType();
    while(type != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if(type == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

            Log.d(Tag, "In start document");
        }
        else if(type == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            Log.d(Tag, "In start tag = "+xpp.getName());
        }
        else if(type == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            Log.d(Tag, "In end tag = "+xpp.getName());

        }
        else if(type == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            Log.d(Tag, "Have text = "+xpp.getText());
            if(xpp.isWhitespace())
            {

            }
            else
            {
                String strquery = xpp.getText();
                db.execSQL(strquery);
            }

        }
        type = xpp.next();
    }
} 
catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Whether code works should most definitely not depend on the IDE you're using, since the code is running on a phone, not on an IDE ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are not instantiating an instance of XmlPullParser. Try:

```
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
```

Also, you need to call:

```
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
```

From the docs:

> Use this call to change the general behaviour of the parser, such as namespace processing >or doctype declaration handling. **This method must be called before the first call to >next or nextToken. Otherwise, an exception is thrown.**
>
> Example: call setFeature(FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true) in order to switch on namespace >processing. The initial settings correspond to the properties requested from the XML Pull >Parser factory. If none were requested, all features are deactivated by default.

Comment: are you saying your problem is resolved? Can you say what solution you used?